# git merge remotes branches

Tags: git, git-remote

I have two remotes to my git repo.

```
origin/master
origin/develop
beta/master
beta/develop
```

my `origin/develop` is 2 commits above the beta/master.I want to merge these two commits on beta/master and push to beta.But when I do `>git merge beta/master origin/develop`,it gives everything upto date.While I see with git log `beta/master`,it doesn't have those commits.

How do I merge these branches ?

Comment: Did u checkout the remote branch locally?

Comment: yes the origin one.then added beta as remote

Comment: Try checking out beta and origin both locally then merge them and then u can push them to remote repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Robin Green's answer is almost correct, but you need to specify the remote branch name, plus you don't need to create a temporary branch:

```
git checkout beta/master
git merge master
git push beta HEAD:refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Won't `git checkout beta/master` try to overwrite the master branch, and fail?

Comment: @RobinGreen No, it checks out a detached HEAD.

Answer (score -1):

As @Vii indicated:

```
git checkout -b betamaster --track beta/master
git merge master
git push betamaster:master
```

Comment: That would push the branch as betamaster, he wants it as master, so: `git push betamaster:master`.

Comment: According to `man git-push` it will push to the tracked branch by default, so mine should work.

Comment: Not true. push.default is by default matching, so betamaster needs to be on 'origin' already, in Git 2.0 it will be 'simple', so by default it won't be pushed, plus it depends on the value of default.matching.

Comment: Ah yes, I got confused by the fact that it will push to the tracked repository. That is not very logical behaviour in conjunction with push.default I must say.